# Godot_rust: load glb from extension doesn't show up

Tags: rust, godot4

The following code won't make the glb file to appear in the scene

```
use godot::engine::{
        global::Error,
        GltfDocument,
        GltfState
};
use godot::prelude::*;

struct MyExtension;

#[gdextension]

unsafe impl ExtensionLibrary for MyExtension {
}


#[derive(GodotClass)]
#[class(base = Node3D)]

struct MyStruct {
        #[base]
        base: Base<Node3D>
}

#[godot_api]

impl INode for MyStruct {
        fn init(mut base: Base<Node3D>) -> Self {

                godot_print!("Hello, world!"); // Prints to the Godot console
                let state: Gd<GltfState> = Default::default();

                let mut doc = GltfDocument::new();

                if GltfDocument::append_from_file(&mut doc, "res://my.glb".into_godot(), state.clone()).ord() != Error::OK.ord() {

                        panic!("Not a proper glb")
                }


                // Load gltf
                let scene = match GltfDocument::generate_scene(&mut doc, state.clone()) {
                        Some(e) => e,
                        None => panic!("Not a proper glb")
                };

                godot_print!("LOADING OK");

                base.add_child(scene);

                Self {
                        base
                }
        }

        fn physics_process(&mut self, delta: f64) {

               
        }
}
```

I reloaded the current project, the console prints LOADING OK but then, nothing.
Any idea why ?